# Datagridview filter with numbers saved as string

Tags: c#, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have a datagrid filled that shows yahoo finance data. The data is loaded via a csv. The datagrid has columns with text and numbers. All data, text and numbers, are shown in string. Now I want to filter one a column that has numbers by the size of the number.

For example: the column has the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Now I just want to see all numbers bigger then 3.

Is there any function or posibility to filter numbers that are saved as string? If yes how can i update the datagrid that it only shows me the row with the nubers after filtering?

Comment: You'd have to convert the string numbers to ints, and then show all that are greater than 3, in ascending order.

Comment: How do you populate the datagridview with values from the csv file?

Comment: @JMad the data shown in the datagrid aren't saved in any array. Is there an operation to delete specific rows from a datagrid with spacific values in a column?

Comment: @MongZhu putting the data from csv into an array an then loading into the datagrid

Comment: can you post the code for the **loading into the datagrid** part?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((item = stream_reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            myArr = item.Split(',');  
            if (a == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < myArr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 5)
                    {
                        string var;
                        string zahl;
                        var = myArr[i];
                        zahl = stringToDoubleToString(var);
                        myArr[i] = zahl;
                    }
                }
            }
            a = 1;
            dataset.Tables["FinData"].Rows.Add(myArr);
```

Comment: this is the method to load the datagrid. Can I use the datagrid rowfilter comparison operators to filter for numbers? If yes how does it work?